# Create list of current time with timezones in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create this list in javascript:

It goes from -11 to +14.

[image]

```
var now = new Date();
```

Gives me this:
*Tue Apr 02 2013 20:48:11 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)*

Tue Apr 02 2013 20:48:11 GMT+0200  is enough, but with the full dayname it would be better. Then I still need to create a list. I can create a select option in javascript e.g.

```
var time = document.getElementById('time'); 
time.options[time.options.length] = new Option(value, text); 
time.options[time.options.length] = new Option(value, text);
```

So I now parts of it but cannot put the whole thing together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the local timezone in which the date is output when using non-UTC methods, so we'll need to cheat on that. Instead, we're going to create different dates (in UTC) and pretend they were in the timezones we want to enumerate:

```
var options = [],
    dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for (var i=-11; i<=14; i++) {
    var d = new Date(); // now
    d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + i); // translate

    // format:
    var na = dayNames[d.getUTCDay()],
        mo = monthNames[d.getUTCMonth()],
        da = d.getUTCDate(),
        ye = d.getUTCFullYear(),
        ho = ("0"+d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2),
        mi = ("0"+d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2),
        of = (i<0?"-":"+")+("0"+Math.abs(i)+"00").slice(-4);
    var text = na+", "+mo+" "+da+", "+ye+" - "+ho+":"+mi+" "+of;
    options.push(new Option(i, text));
}
```